# PHP contact form not landing on right page

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have currently been following a tutorial and so far the contact form works perfect as it should. The only problem I have is when the user clicks submit it takes them to another page saying thank you and not a bootstrap pop up on the same page saying thank you as it should. The form otherwise functions perfectly. Thanks for any help!

contact.php

```
<?php
/*
 *  CONFIGURE EVERYTHING HERE
 */

// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); 

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

/*
 *  LET'S DO THE SENDING
 */

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(0);

try
{

    if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

    $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
    }

    // All the neccessary headers for the email.
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
    );

    // Send email
    mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

    $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

contact.js

```
C$(function () {

    // init the validator
    // validator files are included in the download package
    // otherwise download from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

    $('#contact-form').validator();


    // when the form is submitted
    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        // if the validator does not prevent form submit
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                    // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

contact.html

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>The Beckwood - Scunthorpe</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="header-main">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" >
                     <img src="assets/img/logo.png">

                </a>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                         <li><a href="menu.html">MENU</a></li>
                          <li><a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a></li>
                           <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                            <li><a href="book.html">BOOK A TABLE</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="hero">
            <h1 id="welcome">Contact The Beckwood</h1>
            <p>Please use the below form to contact us. We will try our best to get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
            <div class="btn btn-primary"><a href="menu.html">View Menu</a></div>
            <div class="btn btn-primary"><a href="menu.html">Book a table</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>



</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="intro">
        <h1> Contact Us </h1>
        <p>Welcome to the Beckwood! Here at the beckwood we specialise in authentic home made dishes hand cooked by our chefs.<br> Not only do we offer beautiful food we also provide entertainment, live sports and great quality beer.<br> Not only do we offer beautiful food we also provide entertainment.</p>
    </div>
</div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">

                   <br><br>

                    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

                        <div class="messages"></div>

                        <div class="controls">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_name">First Name *</label>
                                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_lastname">Surname *</label>
                                        <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_email">Email Address *</label>
                                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_phone">Phone Number</label>
                                        <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <p class="text-muted"><br><strong>*</strong> Please complete all fields.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>

                </div><!-- /.8 -->

            </div> <!-- /.row-->

        </div> <!-- /.container-->

<br><br>

<footer id="myFooter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <img id="footerlogo" src="assets/img/logo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h5>Thank you</h5>

                        <p>We would like to thank you for taking the time and visiting thebeckwood.co.uk. If you have any queries please don't hesitate to use the contact us button or give us a quick phone call.</p>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <h5>Navigation</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="book.html">Book</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="social-networks">
                        <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <a href="contact.html"> Contact us </a></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <p>© 2018 The Beckwood.</p>
        </div>
    </footer>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="validator.js"></script>
<script src="contact.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: donde esta el html?

Comment: sorry, added html

Comment: there's no form in that html

Comment: sorry, added correct page!

Comment: **Too much code**. You need to do a better job of troubleshooting this yourself. We are *not* debuggers. You need **isolate the problem** and debug from there. If you're stuck provide a **clear explanation of what isn't working** with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading **[ask]** a good question and **[the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)**. Also, be sure to take the **[tour]** and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem 1:

There is something wrong with the second *jQuery* library.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

When I click the submit button, the following error message is raised:

```
TypeError: $.ajax is not a function[Learn More]     contact.js:18:13
    <anonymous> http://[...my-path...]/contact.js:18:13
    dispatch https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3:10499
    add/q.handle https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3:8561
```

Though there is nothing wrong with the *ajax* request code. So, either use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In any case, don't use two libraries at the same time.

---

#### Problem 2

In your presented `contact.js` page, the first character is `C`, before `$(function () {`. Just remove it from your real code if you have it in there too.

---

#### EDIT 1:

I just tested it and it works ok. E.g. the bootstrap's message *alert* is displayed. So:

- I commented the `mail()` function in *contact.php*. So, please test yourself with `mail()` commented.
- The `https://.../bootstrap.min.js` script doesn't accept any `integrity` attribute. The same applies for the `https://.../bootstrap.min.css` *link* tag. Please resolve these problems too, reedit your question, and give a feedback.

Comment: Hi dakis, I would like to thank you for all your help. I have removed one of the jquery links and the only one there is the 3.2.1 link. It is still linking to a tank you page on submit and not the bootstrap popup on same page though. And also no errors show in the log now!

Comment: @Harry You are welcome and it's nice of you to answer. Now, that's strange about still having the problem... I have a feeling. Could you please update your question with the changes you made? Give us a feedback when you are done reediting.

Comment: Updated my contact.html file!

Comment: This is so strange! ive commented both out the same as you but its still going to the php thank you page! Can't get my head around this one! ill upload validator.js now

Comment: @Harry I just tested with the _validator.js_. It still works fine. So, please empty your cache and cookies, etc, close your browser, reopen it, and try again. P.S: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @Harry I reedited my answer with _**Problem 2**_. That little problem gave me the _new page_ error instead of the alert in my last test. I hope that was your real problem too.

Comment: Hi @dakis. I would just again like to thank you for the time and effort you put into helping me! I cleared my cache, took the comments away and it all seems to be working perfectly. The C you spotted wasn't in my real code. It seems to be working perfect now, just upload it to a host to test and it loads the bootstrap alert on same page and successfully send an email to me. Thank you again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Harry Well, that's great news! ;-) I am glad that I could help you and I thank you too for your appreciation. Have fun and good luck further!

Comment: @Harry P.S 2: If it's about email sending, you could definitely make use of the library _postmark-templates_. See [this](https://github.com/wildbit/postmark-templates) and [this](https://postmarkapp.com/blog/special-delivery-postmark-templates).

Comment: Thanks @Harry Ill take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Just prevent the form from submitting itself

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // REMOVE THIS STATEMENT if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
       var url = "contact.php";
...
```

Comment: I have tried this but its still going to the php page saying thank you?

Comment: @Harry Put all your JS code out of the `C$(function () { }`

Comment: @Harry Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Just noticed this error.. jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).animate is not a function TypeError: $(...).animate is not a function
    at Validator.focusError (file:///C:/Users/Graham/Desktop/web/validator.js:218:21)
    at r.fn.init.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/Graham/Desktop/web/validator.js:206:12)
    at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2:30203)
    at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2:30517) undefined

Comment: https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form thats the example if that helps